# Picture of the product disappears after entering the product

Tags: magento2

I have a problem with newly added products.  When I enter the product, the photo disappears.

when I enter old products, then the pictures work correctly.

Here is movie which description problem: https://streamable.com/oz97w

Answer (score 0):

You products images are probably set as hidden.

Go to your admin panel and to product edit page:

[image]

Check that in each store view and store combinatio then check image types.